# How to set the active slide in ngx owl carousel in Angular

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I am trying to set a slide as active slide based on index. I tried to set the classes active and center.  The newsId value in the below example is from another page which I am getting and verified.

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="newsOptions" class="slider-service">
    <ng-template carouselSlide [ngClass]="{'active center': news.newsId == newsId}" *ngFor="let news of newsSlides">
        .....
    </ng-template>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

Is there any other way to set the active slide?

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? I am having the exact same problem. Can't access its inner elements that are my active slides :c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the owlCar.to(slideIndex:string) function.

Set the Id for each slide:

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="newsOptions" class="slider-service">
    <ng-template carouselSlide *ngFor="let news of newsSlides" [id]="news.newsId">
        .....
    </ng-template>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

And in your component define the owl carousel variable and set the active slide like so

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.scss']
})
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() newsId: string;
  @ViewChild('owlCar', { static: false }) owlCar: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.owlCar.to(this.newsId);
  }
}
```

Just remember that newsId and news.id have to be strings.

Comment: Is it required that the ID exists? Is it a must? Or can we just query the current slide if we check if it has .active class in it... I

Comment: I actually have a question opened for this, and it's been a few days. It's been kinda hard. I tried using your example here a little, but just got some errors. 